# Sir Trevor is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, sirtrevor

I am new to Node.js. I wanted to use Sir Trevor Editor. So, I followed the following procedure.

`npm install sir-trevor
cd node-modules/sir-trevor
npm install
npm run dev`

Then I opened examples/index.html but page showed ordinary html textarea and following javascript errors were shown in the console

- file:///D:/node_modules/sir-trevor/sir-trevor.debug.css Failed to
  load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
- file:///D:/node_modules/sir-trevor/sir-trevor.debug.js Failed to load
  resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND de.js:1
- Uncaught ReferenceError: SirTrevor is not defined index.html:47
- Uncaught ReferenceError: SirTrevor is not defined

Can anyone please help me resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the javascript and css files within node-modules/sir-trevor into your html page?

Comment: In fact, I didn't find any sir-trevor.css or .js file there.

Comment: You should be able to find your files under:

`node_modules/sir-trevor/build/`

There is also a folder with examples under:

`node_modules/sir-trevor/examples/`

Comment: Problem was that my root directory doesn't had chromedriver.exe. I pasted it there and then run "npm test" & "npm run dist". It created build folder and I copied sir-trevor.css & .js from there. Now it is working fine.